# How to get the Active Workbook?

Tags: excel, c#-4.0, vsto

I'm trying to get the Workbook in my application(VSTO) like this :

```
ExcelViewModel mb = new ViewModels.ExcelViewModel();
string NameBox = mb.Workbooks.First().Name;
```

So when Excel open, it already have the default workbook : Book1.xlsx i open for example a second workbook(example.xlsx) but my string NameBox return the "Book1". How can i get the active Workbook? for my example the "example.xlsx" one.

The ExcelViewModel just return me an ObservableCollection of all Workbooks.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found it :

```
Globals.ThisAddin.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Name
```